# How do I take my Powershell object output and turn into c# object?

Tags: c#, powershell

How do I take my Powershell object output and turn into c# object?
I'm trying to get freespace info on remote drives and found this SO thread I'd like to use: [How to get value from powershell script into C# variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44477125/139698)

Maybe transform into following:

```
class MyCSharpObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Used { get; set; }
    public string Free { get; set; }
}
```

Input:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddScript(@"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "Server1" {Get-PSDrive C} | Select-Object PSComputerName,Used,Free
");

                Collection<PSObject> result = ps.Invoke();
                foreach (var outputObject in result)
                {
                    // outputObject contains the result of the powershell script
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
outputObject.ToString()
"@{PSComputerName=Server1; Used=130904309760; Free=136322117632}"
```

Comment: Desired outcome is very unclear here. `outputObject` is already a real .NET object of type [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) - what are you hoping to end up with?

Comment: you can `ps.Invoke<MyCustomType>()` too btw

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I suspect that's unlikely to help here, since the underlying object is a `PSCustomObject` :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Works fine with `PSCustomObject` here is an example of that: https://gist.github.com/santisq/c3fb2575efb827129056a80a1e551808#file-stuff-ps1-L55 :)

Comment: I just learned this ```outputObject.Properties["PSComputerName"].Value
"Server1"```

Comment: By the way you don't need to embed a script, you can construct a proper pipeline of commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [PSObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) you can just use `outputObject.Members` / `outputObject.Properties` to get values and then uses their to fill your custom type.

Example: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5335001/Retrieving-data-from-executed-commands-in-PowerShe

Comment: Seems like I can get a couple of ways. Which one should I use?

```outputObject.Properties["PSComputerName"].Value
"Server1"


outputObject.Members["PSComputerName"].Value
"Server1"```

Comment: @Rod Depends on what you want access to. `Members` contains all adapted or intrinsic members (including any methods attached to the object or the underlying base type) - so if you just want field/property values: use `Properties`